# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback"

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, ios-frameworks

I use xcode4, on a openglES project
i have added code for in-app purchase from the tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases

i have added SystemConfiguration.framework but this errors occurs:

```
Ld /Users/Eros/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blatest-acmdklrqungznggpjewgxuxqsvwo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/blatest.app/blatest normal i386
    cd /Users/Eros/Desktop/blatestDB
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/Eros/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blatest-acmdklrqungznggpjewgxuxqsvwo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Eros/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blatest-acmdklrqungznggpjewgxuxqsvwo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Eros/Desktop/blatestDB -filelist /Users/Eros/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blatest-acmdklrqungznggpjewgxuxqsvwo/Build/Intermediates/blatest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SLQTSOR.build/Objects-normal/i386/blatest.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreGraphics -framework OpenAL -lz -framework MediaPlayer -framework AVFoundation -framework GameKit -framework StoreKit -o /Users/Eros/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blatest-acmdklrqungznggpjewgxuxqsvwo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/blatest.app/blatest

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[Reachability stopNotifier] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[Reachability currentReachabilityStatus] in Reachability.o
      -[Reachability connectionRequired] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      +[Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in Reachability.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

if i delete framework reference the error is the same. 
adding again nothing happens...
in -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit [...] should i see "-framework SystemConfiguration" right?
why is not there?
do anyone has ideas?

pulling up the framework from the project->build phases->link binary with library making it the first framework i have this erros:

```
Ld /Users/Eros/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blatest-acmdklrqungznggpjewgxuxqsvwo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/blatest.app/blatest normal i386
    cd /Users/Eros/Desktop/blatestDB
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/Eros/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blatest-acmdklrqungznggpjewgxuxqsvwo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Eros/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blatest-acmdklrqungznggpjewgxuxqsvwo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Eros/Desktop/blatestDB -filelist /Users/Eros/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blatest-acmdklrqungznggpjewgxuxqsvwo/Build/Intermediates/blatest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SLQTSOR.build/Objects-normal/i386/blatest.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreGraphics -framework OpenAL -lz -framework MediaPlayer -framework AVFoundation -framework GameKit -framework StoreKit -o /Users/Eros/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blatest-acmdklrqungznggpjewgxuxqsvwo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/blatest.app/blatest

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Eros/Desktop/blatestDB/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration, missing required architecture i386 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[Reachability stopNotifier] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[Reachability currentReachabilityStatus] in Reachability.o
      -[Reachability connectionRequired] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      +[Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in Reachability.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

SystemConfiguration is there, the error still there...
what can it be?
thanks

Answer (score 51, accepted):

found it!
i have copied the SystemConfiguration.framework into my project folder (checking the box when i added from xcode).
deleting that folder in my project now compiles well

Answer (score 38):

After adding `SystemConfiguration.framework` from build phases my project compiles well...

have a fun...!

Answer (score 10):

I had also the same problem. I added some frameworks directly with dragging and dropping them.

To resolve it, I deleted all of them and added them through the menu **Target>Build Phases** and then again added all needed frameworks through **Link Binary With Libraries**.

After this, your code should be working fine again.

Answer (score 8):

it's simple.

`scnetworkreachability` callback is labeled as undefined symbol which implies some library or framework file is missing

the prefix **sc** means **system configuration**

- click on the project name choose **Summary** on right side
- click **link binaries and frameworks**
- click plus on it then you can see a drill down with collections of **frameworks and libaries** see if there is anything called 
  **systemConfigurationframework**
- select that and press ok
- Now **build** and **run** the problem is solved

Answer (score 5):

When i was using AFNetworking, after getting these  errors imported 3 frameworks

```
CFNetwork.framework
Security.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
```

All errors will gone.. enjoy !!!

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned above, after importing the following 3 frameworks, it works!

```
    CFNetwork.framework
    Security.framework
    SystemConfiguration.framework
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out I also got a problem simular to this.

I copied some files over to xcode and accidently had "ProjectTests" selected instead of the project. Just delete the files and re-add them to your project making sure the main project ( not the unit tests) is selected

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after an update from repo.

The solution that worked for me was to delete references from project for all classes and add them again. The problem is that there is a big possibility to mess up the repo synchronization.