# Apple Mac-O linker Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, xcode6

I am at a point where I don't know how to solve this issue. I have getting 9 *Apple Mac-O linker errors*. Of course it's a bunch of error codes that I don't understand. You can have a look at the screenshot to better diagnose the issue at hand.

[image: Apple Mac-O linker error screenshot]

As you can see in there I am using parse as my backend, (Users, push notifications, messaging protocols...etc). I already have parse/parse.h imported in the AppDelegate.m, AppDelegate.h, ViewController.m and main.m file which sits in the supporting files folder in your project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "\_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112573/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-scnetworkreachabilitysetcallback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the dependencies -- see step 3 of: https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing

The first few undefined symbols are SCNetworkReachabilityxxx which is part of SystemConfiguration.framework, which is the last library in the list.  Parse requires all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added following frameworks when you are integrating parse in your app:

```
AudioToolbox.framework
CFNetwork.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
CoreLocation.framework
libz.1.1.3.dylib
MobileCoreServices.framework
QuartzCore.framework
Security.framework
StoreKit.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework  //You are missing this
```